# filter search results by clicking checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, html, cakephp

I have a search page where a user can type in a search box, or they can use an alphabetical list to search for the record they're looking for. Eg they click 'a' and all the records beginning with the letter 'a' appear.

I'd also like to have it so that each record has a number of tags, and I'd then like to be able to filter records according to which tags have been selected - preferably using check boxes.

For example, perhaps the tags would be colored and the records represented shoes. There would be check boxes for blue, yellow, black, brown and so on. At first all colors would be shown, but if the user clicks on brown then all but the brown shoes disappear.

I am using CakePHP

Comment: i think you'd better use ajax to filter result on client side rather than make it on the server side via php

Comment: hey pal, thanks for the suggestion. I'll go and start reading up on ajax then. If you fancied giving me a bit of a roadmap of what to look at first or how I'd go about doing what I want, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to look into getting JSON/AJAX Results in CakePHP.
Then check out how events can be used in jQuery. 
Then you can load them for your search and set a jQuery event on your checkboxes that trigger a function.
It is all quite simple and jQuery has very good documentation.

Comment: Here are some links:
- [Google for CakePHP ajax json](http://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp%20ajax%20json)
- [Check out jQuery checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)
- [Check out jQuery change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 // cakephp view
 echo $this->Form->checkbox("Model.color.0", array("value"=>"green"));

 // cakephp controller
 $filtered = $this->Model->find("all", array(
   "conditions"=> array(
     // ...
   ) + $this->data
 ));
 //or
 $this->paginate['conditions'] = array(
   //...
 ) + $this->data;
 $filtered=$this->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI Autocomplete Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) is what you are looking for.

You can try out a demo here - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#demo

In the demo, they have used a static local option. But you can use a remote URL also which results a particular list based on your search term. Look at the various options.

Do give it a try and if you experience problems (I am sure you will), ask again here.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'll have a look at it but I've just managed to get cakephp ajax helper's autocomplete working on the search box on that page and I've heard there are problems using jquery with the default prototype library. Also from what I know about autocomplete I've no idea how I'd get that to translate into checkboxes, but I'll read up on the remote URL thingy. Would you mind giving me a bit more info? I'm a total newb at this. thanks!

Comment: Sorry I do not have experience with cakePHP and prototype. I work with Zend Framework and jQuery :)